# How to determine which package has a particular dependency constraint?

Tags: meteor, atmosphere.js, meteor-cordova

```
> meteor update
The following top-level dependencies were not updated to the very latest version available:
 * mdg:camera 1.2.0 (1.3.0 is available)     

> meteor add mdg:camera@1.3.0
 => Errors while adding packages:             

While selecting package versions:
error: Conflict: Constraint isobuild:cordova@5.4.0 is not satisfied by isobuild:cordova 5.2.0.
Constraints on package "isobuild:cordova":
* isobuild:cordova@5.4.0 <- mdg:camera 1.3.0
```

So I think I need to figure out which package depends on `isobuild:cordova 5.2.0` and upgrade/edit it do use `5.4.0`?

Comment: I've got the same problem with a different mdg package. I'm totally guessing here, but maybe the newer versions are ready for Meteor 1.3, and aren't compatible with Meteor 1.2?